# How to mix / blend between 2 vertex positions based on distance from camera?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader, webgl

I'm trying to mix / blend between 2 different vertex positions depending on the distance from the camera. Specifically, I'm trying to create an effect that blends between a horizontal plane closer to the camera and a vertical plane in the distance. The result should be a curved plane going away and up from the current camera position.

I want to blend from this (a plane flat on the ground):
[image]

To this (the same plane, just rotated 90 degrees):
[image]

The implementation I have so far feels close but I just can't put my finger on what pieces I need to finish it. I took an approach from [a similar Tangram demo](https://github.com/meetar/bendy-map) ([shader code](https://github.com/meetar/bendy-map/blob/master/scene.yaml)), however I'm unable to get results anywhere near this. The Tangram example is also using a complete different setup to what I'm using in Three.js so I've not been able to replicate everything.

This is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/robhawkes/a97tu864/

```
varying float distance;

mat4 rotateX(float rotationX) {
  return mat4(
    vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0),
    vec4(0.0,cos(rotationX),-sin(rotationX),0.0),
    vec4(0.0,sin(rotationX),cos(rotationX),0.0),
    vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)
  );
}

void main() 
{
  vec4 vPosition = vec4(position, 1.0);
  vec4 modelViewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vPosition;

  float bend = radians(-90.0);
  vec4 newPos = rotateX(bend) * vPosition;

  distance = -modelViewPosition.z;

  // Show bent position
  //gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * newPos;

  float factor = 0.0;

  //if (vPosition.x > 0.0) {
  //    factor = 1.0;
  //}

  //factor = clamp(0.0, 1.0, distance / 2000.0);

  vPosition = mix(vPosition, newPos, factor);

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vPosition;
}
```

I'm doing the following:

- Calculate the rotated position of the vertex (the vertical version)
- Find the distance from the vertex to the camera
- Use `mix` to blend between the horizontal position and vertical position depending on the distance

I've tried multiple approaches and I just can't seem to get it to work correctly.

Any ideas? Even pointing me down the right path will be immensely helpful as my shader/matrix knowledge is limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major issue is, that you tessellate the [`THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/PlaneBufferGeometry) in width segments, but not in height segments:

```
groundGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 
    1000, 10000, 
    100,    // <----- widthSegments 
    100 );  // <----- heightSegments is missing
```

Now you can use the z coordinate of the view space  for the interpolation:

```
float factor = -modelViewPosition.z / 2000.0;
```

```js
var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
var groundGeometry, groundMaterial, groundMesh;
var ambientLight;

init();
initLight();
initGround();
animate();

function init() {
 
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10000 );
  camera.position.y = 500;
  camera.position.z = 1000;
  
  controls = new THREE.MapControls( camera );
  controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  
  scene.add(camera);
  
  var axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper( 500 );
 scene.add( axesHelper );

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
 
}

function initLight() {
  ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 );
 scene.add( ambientLight );
}

function initGround() {
 groundMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
    transparent: true
  });
  
  groundGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 1000, 10000, 100, 100 );
  groundMesh = new THREE.Mesh( groundGeometry, groundMaterial );
  groundMesh.position.z = -3000;
  groundMesh.position.y = -100;
  groundMesh.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2)
  scene.add( groundMesh );
}

function animate() {
 
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  
  controls.update();
  
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
 
}
```

```html
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">
varying float distance;

mat4 rotateX(float rotationX) {
  return mat4(
    vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0),
    vec4(0.0,cos(rotationX),-sin(rotationX),0.0),
    vec4(0.0,sin(rotationX),cos(rotationX),0.0),
    vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)
  );
}

void main() 
{
  vec4 vPosition = vec4(position, 1.0);
  vec4 modelViewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vPosition;
    
  float bend = radians(-90.0);
  vec4 newPos = rotateX(bend) * vPosition;
  
  distance = -modelViewPosition.z;
  
  float factor = -modelViewPosition.z / 2000.0;
  
  vPosition = mix(vPosition, newPos, factor);
  
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vPosition;
}
</script>
<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShader">
varying float distance;

void main() {
  if (distance < 3000.0) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  } else {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
}
</script>

<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/controls/MapControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I felt like I was close so it's good to know that it was just a silly mistake with the definition of the plane geometry. I should have spotted that.